# product id in purchases.products.get, when multiple products are purchased

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, google-play-developer-api

In our app, there are multiple products, one can add products to a cart and order.

For a purchase token which corresponds to a order with multiple orders, if I call following API,

[https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/{packageName}/purchases/products/{productId}/tokens/{token}](https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/%7BpackageName%7D/purchases/products/%7BproductId%7D/tokens/%7Btoken%7D)

what should be productId here ?

I noticed the value in productId field doesn't matter incase of multiple products purchase token. Even if I give soe random string here, API doesn't fail.

I get following response:

```
{
    "purchaseTimeMillis": "1665926426438",
    "purchaseState": 1,
    "consumptionState": 0,
    "developerPayload": "",
    "orderId": "GPA.3303-6009-6961-91689",
    "purchaseType": 0,
    "acknowledgementState": 0,
    "kind": "androidpublisher#productPurchase",
    "obfuscatedExternalAccountId": "u-c55c0815-9b0d-4c07-a032-272985dee80b",
    "regionCode": "IN"
}
```

Here again there is no mention of products purchased.

My question is how do I verify which products were purchased ?